# How does this TensorFlow sample actually update the weights to find the solution

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gradient-descent

New to tensorflow, python and numpy (I guess that's everything in this sample)

In the code below I (almost) understand that the update_weights.run() call in the loop is calculating the loss and developing new weights. What I don't see is how this actually causes the weights to be changed.

The point I'm stuck on is commented # THIS IS WHAT I DONT UNDERSTAND

What is the relationship between the update_weights.run() and the new values being placed in weights? - Or perhaps; how come when weights.eval is called after the loop that the values have changed?

Thanks for any help

```
#@test {"output": "ignore"}

# Import tf
import tensorflow as tf

# Numpy is Num-Pie n dimensional arrays
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy
import numpy as np

# Plotting library
# http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %matplotlib magic
# http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magics-explained
%matplotlib inline

# Set up the data with a noisy linear relationship between X and Y.
# Variable?
num_examples = 5
noise_factor = 1.5
line_x_range = (-10,10)

#Just variables in Python
# np.linspace - Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
X = np.array([
        np.linspace(line_x_range[0], line_x_range[1], num_examples), 
        np.linspace(line_x_range[0], line_x_range[1], num_examples)
    ])

# Plot out the starting data
# plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
# plt.scatter(X[0], X[1])
# plt.show()

# npm.random.randn - Return a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution.
# Generate noise for x and y (2)
noise = np.random.randn(2, num_examples) * noise_factor

# plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
# plt.scatter(noise[0],noise[1])
# plt.show()

# += on an np.array
X += noise

# The 'Answer' polyfit to the noisy data
answer_m, answer_b = np.polyfit(X[0], X[1], 1)


# Destructuring Assignment - http://codeschool.org/python-additional-miscellany/
x, y = X

# plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
# plt.scatter(x, y)
# plt.show()

# np.array
# for a in x
#  [(1., a) for a in [1,2,3]] => [(1.0, 1), (1.0, 2), (1.0, 3)]
# numpy.ndarray.astype - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html 
# Copy of the array, cast to a specified type.
x_with_bias = np.array([(1., a) for a in x]).astype(np.float32)

#Just variables in Python
# The difference between our current outputs and the training outputs over time
# Starts high and decreases
losses = []
history = []
training_steps = 50
learning_rate = 0.002

# Start the session and give it a variable name sess 
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Set up all the tensors, variables, and operations.
  # Creates a constant tensor
  input = tf.constant(x_with_bias)
  # Transpose the ndarray y of random float numbers
  target = tf.constant(np.transpose([y]).astype(np.float32))
  # Start with random weights
  weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1], 0, 0.1))

  # Initialize variables ...?obscure?
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print('Initialization complete')

  # tf.matmul - Matrix Multiplication
  # What are yhat? Why this name?
  yhat = tf.matmul(input, weights)

  # tf.sub - Matrix Subtraction
  yerror = tf.sub(yhat, target)

  # tf.nn.l2_loss - Computes half the L2 norm of a tensor without the sqrt
  # loss function?
  loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(yerror)

  # tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer - Not sure how this is updating the weights tensor?
  # What is it operating on?
  update_weights = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

  # _ in Python is conventionally used for a throwaway variable
  for step in range(training_steps):
    # Repeatedly run the operations, updating the TensorFlow variable.
    # THIS IS WHAT I DONT UNDERSTAND
    update_weights.run()
    losses.append(loss.eval())
    b, m = weights.eval()
    history.append((b,m,step))

  # Training is done, get the final values for the graphs
  betas = weights.eval()
  yhat = yhat.eval()

# Show the fit and the loss over time.
# destructuring assignment
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

# Adjust whitespace between plots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.2)

# Output size of the figure
fig.set_size_inches(12, 4)

ax1.set_title("Final Data Fit")
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.axis([-15, 15, -15, 15])

# Scatter plot data x and y (pairs?) set with 60% opacity
ax1.scatter(x, y, alpha=.6)
# Scatter plot x and np.transpose(yhat)[0] (must be same length), in red, 50% transparency
# these appear to be the x values mapped onto the 
ax1.scatter(x, np.transpose(yhat)[0], c="r", alpha=.5)

# Add the line along the slope defined by betas (whatever that is)
ax1.plot(line_x_range, [betas[0] + a * betas[1] for a in line_x_range], "g", alpha=0.6)

# This polyfit coefficients are reversed in order vs the betas
ax1.plot(line_x_range, [answer_m * a + answer_b for a in line_x_range], "r", alpha=0.3)


ax2.set_title("Loss over Time")

# Create a range of intefers from 0 to training_steps and plot the losses as a curve
ax2.plot(range(0, training_steps), losses)

ax2.set_ylabel("Loss")
ax2.set_xlabel("Training steps")

ax3.set_title("Slope over Time")
ax3.axis('equal')
ax3.axis([-15, 15, -15, 15])

for b, m, step in history:
  ax3.plot(line_x_range, [b + a * m for a in line_x_range], "g", alpha=0.2)

# This line seems to be superfluous removing it doesn't change the behaviour
plt.show()
```

Comment: Without looking into tensorflow one can only guess that both are actually the same variable. Have you debugged this particular section?

Comment: No, I've not seen a debugger for tensorflow yet, but this is a great idea! Would you recommend tensortboard? As in here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html

Comment: In my opinion you should start by using matplotlib like you did before going to Tensorboard, which requires a good comprehension of Tensorflow's internal way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so update_weights() is calling a minimizer on the loss that you defined to be the error between your prediction and the target.

What it will do is it will add some small quantity to the weights (how small is controlled by the learning_rate parameter) to make your loss decrease and hence to make your predictions "truer".

This is what happens when you call update_weights() so after the call your weights have changed from a small value and if everything went according to the plan your loss value has decreased.

What you want is follow the evolution of your loss and the weights see for example if the loss is really decreasing (and your algorithm works) or if the weights are changing a lot or maybe to visualize them.

You can gain a lot of insights by visualizing how the loss is changing.
This is why you have to see the full history of the evolution of the parameters and loss; That is why you eval them at each step.

The eval or run operation is different when you do it on the minimizer and on the parameters when you do it on the minimizer it will **apply** the minimizer to the weights when you do it on the weights it simply **evaluates** them.
I strongly advise you to read [this website](http://cs231n.github.io/) where the author explains far better than me what is going on and in more details.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Jean, this is very helpful, however the bit I'm missing is how does update_weights() even get a reference to the 'weights' to change them? I don't see it passed in as a parameter, is it somehow worked out through the loss function, yerror, yhat chain of things (are they called tensors?) ?

Comment: Tensorflow's idea is to use a computation graph. When you run some line of code like W=tf.Variable() or y=tf.matmul(W,x) nodes are created in this graph. Then when you run the minimizer Tensorflow somehow goes through the whole graph to backpropagate the cost into each and every variable that you defined and that is connected to it (the cost).

Comment: This is explained in great length in this article: [link](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf).

Comment: To rephrase: as the loss implicitely depends on the variable weights when you apply minimize(loss) it gets access to the weights through the graph.